# display bootstrap alerts on google map

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

Has anyone succeeded in displaying a bootstrap alert on a google map? I tried:

```
 <div id="map" style="height:100%">
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                <strong>Success!</strong> Indicates a successful or positive action.
            </div>
        </div>
```

Also with a very high z-index but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#map` `<div>` is just a container for anything that google want to inject. Whatever markup you place in there will be removed when the map is initialized.

Instead place the map inside a parent container along with the alert markup, then set the alert to have `position: absolute` and optionally some extra styling like the position; `z-index` is not needed.

This is in general how you would place an element on top of another element, and there is absolutely no difference because it is a google maps container :

```
<div class="map-cnt">
  <div id="map" style="height:100%"></div>  
  <div class="alert alert-success map-alert">
     <strong>Success!</strong> Indicates a successful or positive action.
  </div>  
</div>
```

CSS

```
.map-cnt {
  height: 200px;
}
.map-alert {
  position: absolute; 
  left: 20%;
  top: 30%; 
}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/s4z25xvk/**